# Searching Elasticsearch document by existing field not found but the field exists

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

First of all, I must say I'm on Elasticsearch 5.6.16

I'm trying to figuring out what's happening here. I have several documents indexed with this mapping (I copied the document directly from Kibana):

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "Outbreak_10346",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "outbreakId": 10346,
    "reference": "XX-AD-2021-00003",
    "countryCode": "BE",
    "adisNotificationReasonType": {
      "code": "TERRESTRIAL"
    },
    "approximateLocation": false,
    "latitude": 50.93766,
    "longitude": 3.97156,
    "adminZoneLevelOne": {
      "zoneId": 40,
      "zoneCode": "BE2"
    },
    "affectedSpecies": [
      {
        "speciesId": 16703,
        "name": "Swine",
        "measuringUnit": "ANIMAL",
        "casesQuantity": 10,
        "deadQuantity": 1,
        "susceptibleQuantity": 100,
        "isAquatic": false
      }
    ],
    "affectedSpeciesTotalSusceptible": 100,
    "affectedSpeciesTotalCases": 10
  }
}
```

If I do this query in Kibana:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "adminZoneLevelOne"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get any results. But if I change the field to any of the others I find the documents.
Also, when I retrieve the documents I can access the `adminZoneLevelOne` field.

How's this possible? Why Elasticsearch doesn't find any document with that field?

The index mapping for `adminZoneLevelOne` field is:

```
  "adminZoneLevelOne": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "zoneCode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "WHITESPACE"
      },
      "zoneId": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
```

And for `adisNotificationReasonType` that works fine, is:

```
  "adisNotificationReasonType": {
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "LOWERCASE_KEYWORD"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since `adminZoneLevelOne` is of nested type, you need to use exists query along with the [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) as**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "adminZoneLevelOne",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "adminZoneLevelOne"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I search by "affectedSpecies" or "adisNotificationReasonType" I find the documents.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: Indeed, adminZoneLevelOne.zoneCode.keyword doesn't exist, but adisNotificationReasonType.code.keyword does, so it is the way I build the document?

Comment: I've added the index mapping for a couple of fields, one that works and the one that doesn't

Comment: What I see is that `adminZoneLevelOne` is a nested field.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda please go through the EDIT 2 part of the answer

Comment: I still don't get any result with the "nested_query".

Comment: I'll try to make the field not nested.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda try with the modified query as shown in the answer. Let me know if this resolves your issue? There is no need to make field not `nested`

Comment: Yep, the update of the query works fine. Thanks!.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda glad I could help you :-)